# Docusaurus V2 - Use page title for og:title on docs

Tags: docusaurus

At the moment my `og:title` is using the title defined in the config not the current doc title.

```
---
id: my_id
title: My Title ** I want it to pull in this
sidebar_label: My Title
---
```

I've changed my file from `.md` to `.mdx` and tried to define this in the `<Head>` component but this didn't work.

```js
import Head from '@docusaurus/Head';

<Head>
  <meta property="og:title" content="My custom title" />
</Head>
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug. We've fixed it in https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/pull/2475

Comment: Thank you for fixing the issue

Answer (score 0):

For now I've used `swizzle` to override the `DocItem` component.

```sh
yarn docusaurus swizzle @docusaurus/theme-classic DocItem
```